# Request for help regarding EF core Data Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In My DataBase a particular field data can be string or int . What data type I need to use in my Asp.net core MVC EF project?

Comment: Could you please share what you are going to save it? For example, `Name`, `date Of birth` or, `amount`? [You could check a few samples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli#create-the-model) So that we can suggest you.

Comment: Its a field which name is "PI_Number" which data can be string or int. like a "PI Document Number can be  "abc12564" or just "1245"

Comment: Then of course string type means proforma invoice number right?  If so then you should keep in string type without any confusion

Comment: Yah!! you are right .Its Proforma Invoice. But If I use string then how can it takes int type value?

Comment: As it's a combination of alpha numerical characters so it should be string you can keep integers as string as well.

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved? Do you need an example? If you need I can provide you with an example for your reference. let me know if you require that.